# Create the Haversine Formula in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to incorporate the haversine formula into a mysql database so that I can call the function from a PHP script.

For example,
    in PHP I will call: Select * from postcodes where code = "CW84AD", Select * from postcodes where code = "CH73TD".

Could I call something like "Select haversine(CW84AD, CH73TD)"?

Comment: It is possible, yes.... it's called a user-defined function though you'd need to pass arguments correctly from the SQL query

Comment: Why do you call this a Haversine function? That's confusing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 0):

You can't create function because function returns only one rows.

If you want to return more than one row you can create procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE haversine(IN arg1 VARCHAR(255), IN arg2 VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
        Select * from postcodes where code = arg1 or code= arg2;

 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then You can call this procedure.

CALL haversine('CW84AD','CH73TD');